# Selecting by month in date/time field using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, date

I would like to select by a specific month from my date/time field in ArcGIS, and just can't seem to find a statement that will work.

I have multiple years and multiple days, but want to filter those out and only choose the records from the month of May.

Comment: Where is your data stored? fGDB? shapefile? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: How are you searching for the data? I know there is a bug where the time element of datetime doesn't show if the time is midnight. Remember, too, that locale is important in the order of data, months, especially so. There are a whole host of operations you can use in Python or VBS to disseminate date data, as well as on the Oracle side (Between, etc...).

Comment: Data is stored in a shapefile.

Comment: thank you! was useful - I did my selection by dates very quickly!

Comment: welcome to GIS.StackExchange.  The "Your Answer" is meant for potential answers to the question at hand, not comments.  Feel free to leave a comment under the answer that worked best for you, and press the "upvote" button to give more credibility to that answer.  That way new readers will be able to guage which answer is most likely to help.

Comment: I migrated your reply, @Anna, to a comment here.  It was not possible to determine which post you are referencing as "useful" because the sequence in which replies are presented varies.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps something like this:

1. Open the shapefile attribute table and click Options > Select By Attributes
2. Type `DatePart("M", [YourDateField]) = 5` (for May) and click Apply.

Comment: This code sample works really well.  I actually used it to calc a new field values for month based upon the Month DatePart.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax varies depending on where the data is being fetched from (file gdb, shapefile, personal gdb, Oracle, DB2, etc.).

**File Geodatabase, shapefiles,** and file-based data such as **dbf** files:

Everything in May:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "MyDate") = 05
```

Before noon:

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM "MyDate") < 12
```

**Personal** Geodatabase (**.mdb**):

```
DATEPART("m", [MyDate]) = 05
```

**SQL Server**:

```
DATEPART(month, MyDate) = 05
```

For more details such as further limitations and query by hour/year/etc. see the Esri [HowTo: Search for specific parts of a date stored in a Date-Time field](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40088). For extended examples using Field Calculator see ArcWatch [Simplify Date and Time Calculations](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/1210/tip.html).

Comment: Just want add a comment to help others reading this answer. I was making the mistake of wrapping the month value in quotes (e.g. EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "MyDate") = '05') thinking I was returning a string but EXTRACT returns the day, month or year as an integer.

Answer (score 6):

In ArcGIS 10 (probably works similarly in earlier versions in the select by attributes tool you can specify the selection statement to have a range between the beginning of the month and the end of the month, but the syntax in ArcMap is strange.

The selection query should look like this:

```
"DateField" >= date '05/01/2011 00:00:00' AND "DateField" < date '06/01/2011 00:00:00'
```

I used excel to make a long list of month ranges and then used model builder to make a script to batch select by the above query, update an ‘order by’ field, and then export to a standalone filegeodatabase featureclass.

Comment: my source data is in a file geodatabase.

Comment: This works! It is too bad that you would have to write it out for EACH year in the dataset. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like...

```
Select DatePart(MM, GetDate()) as Current_Month
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the appropriate database function to query out the month from the date field. For example, in Oracle you could select by attribute where `To_Char([date],'MM') = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple script to write would be to get the date in it's entirety, then split it:

```
Time = "2011-04-06 11:26:51"
Month = newTime.split("-")[1]
```

Then do your comparison on the Month value

Answer (score 0):

Horrible hack, but you could export your attribute table to .csv; import into Excel, and parse the year/month/day in excel. Then join that Excel worksheet to your table, and sort on the month.