# How do I select all points from a range of dates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, select-by-attribute, date

Is there a way to select points from a range of dates to create a new layer? I want to clean up my data by making all points from previous years a separate layer but doing a selection by attributes and choosing each date individually is taking way too long.It would be perfect if there was a way to query out all points from 2013, for example.

Comment: Do you have a field that is populated with a date?

Comment: What software are you using? From your terminology I'm guessing ArcGIS, but methods and tools may differ from software to software. What format/data type is your date field (string, actual date field)? For that matter what format is your data (shapefile, feature class in geodatabase)?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.1 and the data I'm referring to is a layer from a feature class in a geodatabase. The data already has a date collected field. I could in theory select by attribut and select dates individually but I have thousands of points to go through.

Comment: @Zev Have you tried to use the Select by Attribute tool, to select records that don't equal (<>) 2013? Once this selection is done, you can export the selected data, or use it as needed. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000

Comment: The points I have came from field collections on ArcPad, so the date field is listed as (for example): date'2013-07-03 13:32.19'  so I haven't been able figure out a syntax for selecting based on just the year. Thanks so much for your suggestions.

Comment: ArcGIS has some specific functions for working with dates. You can see some of them in the Select by Attributes window - by clicking the 'date' radio button it should change the list of available functions on the right. Note it makes a difference whether you're using VBScript or Python syntax as to what shows up. Since you've clarified you have an actual date field, if you wanted to select only based on year you'd need a date strip part function to extract just the year portion of the value. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/ for some examples.

Answer (score 5):

You can use greater-than and less-than operators on dates, so something like this:

```
"CHANGE_DATE" > date '2012-12-31 00:00:00' AND "CHANGE_DATE" < date '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Would work to grab all the dates for the year 2013. Note that the specific syntax of the query can change slightly depending on the data source. The above is for a file geodatabase.